# Right drivers side tyre scraped curb, missing chunk - Honda Fit

Tags: honda, tires, sidewall-damage, wheels, fit

Please forgive me if I’m not using the correct terms, I know nothing about cars.
Earlier today I was driving in a parking lot and scraped up against a curb. Upon further inspection the car itself is driving OK but the right drivers side tyre is missing a large chunk from it, and the rim has been scraped as well.

[image: Sorry for the terrible picture, it’s dark out.]

As of now it’s holding air and not leaking. Just wondering what my chances are of having to replace this tyre?

Comment: in your image is not very clear the thickness of the mentioned chunk. Seems big enough, but could upload a new picture?

Answer (score 1):

If a piece is missing from the sidewall, I would recommend replacing the tire ASAP. I've done a few seasons myself as a tire technician in a couple different shops and seen nothing but bad things happen with tires that have sidewall damage. As for the wheel, it could be repairable depending on the extent of they're damage (photo isn't too clear do I cannot tell the extent).